# List of iterators to collect entries from various lists

Tags: c++, linked-list, conceptual, qlist, qlinkedlist

A class `TaskGroup` mainly contains a list of `Task`s. I want to collect certain tasks `ta1`, `ta2`, `tb3`, ... from various groups `ga`, `gb`, `gc`, ... and use this list in a display window/class. The choice of tasks for the collection is of no concern for this question.

(As the question is rather conceptual than technical, the examples are mostly pseudo code. Since I'm using Qt in this particular case, I'll be using Qt classes, but the question shouldn't be limited to this case.)

```
class Task;

class TaskGroup {
    QString name;
    QList<Task> tasklist;
    ...
}
```

The objects from the text above, `ta1` etc, should be understood as "first task from group `ga`" etc.

Now, this wouldn't be a problem:

```
QList<Task> collection;
collection.append(ga.getTask(1));
...
collection.append(gb.getTask(3));
...

doSomethingWithTheCollection(collection);
```

The use case is something like "create tasks organized in lists --> choose certain tasks --> add them to a TO DO list (collection) --> display collection --> fulfill tasks --> delete accomplished task from collection AND its original list one at a time --> repeat".
The problem with the aforementioned implementation is that I cannot delete the entry in the original group (not even by passing by reference or pointer), because just the object is part of the collection.

I therefore would need to make the collection a list of iterators!

```
QList<QList<Task>::iterator> collection;
collection.append(ga.getIteratorToTask(1));
...
```

Because I can then use the respective tasks via dereferencing and upon completion I can erase it by `collection[x].erase();` and they disappear from the original list.

Am I thinking right so far? Or is this even a sophisticated concept?

If there is more than one quest per list in the collection I have to use `QLinkedList`, because after manipulation of a general `QList`, iterators become invalid... Should I therefore implement the `TaskGroup` class with a `QLinkedList` instead of a `QList`?

### EDIT

While putting that concept into practice, I discovered in disappointment that `erase(iterator)` is part of the `QList` class and not of the iterator itself. It seems, I thus cannot delete the entry in the original list, as I wished, via just the iterator... I need the list for that. Is there any solution to that?
Maybe using the Java-like `QMutableListIterator` and its `remove()` method instead of `QList<Task>::iterator`? `QMutableListIterator` has the disadvantage of not supporting "iterator arithemtics". (I don't want to pass the entire list...could I pass a function pointer to the respective `QList<Task>::erase()` function? I know this sounds crazy but at this point, I want to know if my approach is somehow doable...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your solution sounds reasonable, and you are correct that you would need to use a `QLinkedList` to avoid iterator invalidation.

An alternative design would be to give `Task`s a back-pointer to the `TaskGroup` that owns them, and add a method to `TaskGroup` to remove a `Task`. The `Task` can then request that it is removed from the `TaskGroup` when it has been completed.

Something like the following (which I haven't tried):

```
void Task::Complete()
{
    parent->RemoveTask(*this);
}

void TaskGroup::RemoveTask(Task& task)
{
    tasklist.removeAll(task);
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you for the alternative idea. That also sounds reasonable! You mean just something like a `QList<Task>* parent` pointer which is assigned a value when the task is added to a `TaskGroup`? I would be grateful, if you added a very brief implementation (pseudo code), because although I totally understand the idea, I'm a bit unsure about putting it into practice. Removing a task would be part of the task group, however the request would come from the task itself. How does the group know _which_ task to delete? And how does this affect other tasks in the collection? Thank you!

Comment: I've added how I think it might look to my answer.

Comment: Ah, sure... let the list itself delete the respective tasks... does it still need to be a linked list? Not in this design, if I find correctly...?

Comment: It doesn't need to be a linked list as long as you don't have any iterators operating over `tasklist` list when you remove a task.

Comment: I tried to implement my idea to day and stumbled over the fact that `iterator` has no remove function (it's part of the `QLists`'s methods! See my edit... do you have an idea? :(

Comment: And the `QMutableListIterator` wont accept syntax `it += 5;` for instance, which I (want to) use like with `QList::iterator`...

Comment: It might be a good idea to use the pattern I suggested then, as it doesn't require you to use iterators.

Comment: You're probably right... although I'm truly disappointed... this solution seemed so neat. :(