# Deleting STL-container element via iterator only

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Is there a way to delete an element from an `STL` container (be it `list`, `vector`, ...) only via an iterator pointing to the element to be deleted, but *without* providing the container object it resides in (i.e. without directly using the container memberfunction `container<T>::iterator container<T>.erase(container<T>::iterator)`?

(Follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41532952/list-of-iterators-to-collect-entries-from-various-lists))

Comment: @LCsa  You can use another member function like for example pop_back.:)

Comment: I see that from time to time and have often wondered, "What is the address of a non-breaking space?"

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The joke about it is not to use the actual container at all. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Imagine what would have to happen in order for the standard to provide a way to do this. `std::vector<T>::iterator` could not be a simple `T*`. Instead it would have to contain enough information for the library to be able to "find" the vector to which it belongs, such as a pointer to the vector itself. Thus, if the standard imposed a requirement to make it possible to delete an element given only an iterator, it would force the standard library to add overhead that would slow down all users of the container.

Comment: If you are dealing with ranges, you sort of can do this in the style of `std::remove`, by moving all of the elements up, provided you start with a range. You'll have a new range at the end though and likely would have to use `std::vector<>::erase` or similar afterwards though.

Comment: So, there is no way to do this, if I do not also provide the container the iterator points to?

Do you have an idea of how to solve the problem (as described in the linked question?)